# How to cancel out roll and pitch in IMU?

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I bought a quite decent IMU called Bosch BN055. It is a 9-DOF IMU.
The thing is, I have a differential drive robot and runs on a flat surface, which means I do not need roll and pitch, only YAW.

I am using robot_localization to fuse odometry vx,vy and IMU roll, pitch and yaw. My robot sometimes creates a vibration which causes my IMU to drift and making my robot to spin and roll.

I have tried to fuse robot_localization with only YAW values but after some time, ROS will throw an error stating that the combined quaternion value should equal to 1 and I get it, as I making roll and pitch to be 0, when IMU thinks it has been rotated in those directions, the YAW values become different.

How can I cope with that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313276/how-to-cancel-out-roll-and-pitch-in-imu?/) by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 361 on 2019-01-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2019-01-21**:
do you convert yaw in quarternian by yourself or using tf?(if you convert by yourself can you share your code)

**Comment by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on 2019-01-21**:
@hamid I am using library which you can find here: [LINK](https://github.com/jetsonhacks/rtimulib_ros)

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2019-01-21**:
that code doesn't convert eurl angle to quarternian if i realize correctly you set imu_msg.orientation.x and imu_msg.orientation.y to zero and publish the msg?am i right?

**Comment by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on 2019-01-21**:
@hamid the libary publishes imu msg to /imu. Yes, I did that before but after sometime that will give me an error as quaternion should add up to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if you want to use only yaw , first you have to convert quarternian to eurl angle and then convert yaw in quarternian then publish msg . you can use something like this code:

```
  float yaw;
  tf::Quaternion robot_imu;
  robot_imu.setX(msg->orientation.x);
  robot_imu.setY(msg->orientation.y);
  robot_imu.setZ(msg->orientation.z);
  robot_imu.setW(msg->orientation.w);
  yaw_ = tf::getYaw(robot_imu);
  tf::Quaternion yaw(tf::createQuaternionFromYaw(yaw_));
```

you can't simply set x and y to zero.

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2019-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on 2019-01-22**:
@hamid okay that makes sense, so in yaw format, I would just cancel out roll and pitch and keep only way and convert back to Q